# Enter key not working to start new line in Aptana?

Tags: aptana3

I've recently connected a (non Apple) external keyboard to my Macbook Air. This works as expected in every application apart from Aptana where the "Enter" key does not do anything, including starting a new line. It seems stupid to have to use the tiny MBA keyboard whenever I need to code, so is there a fix for this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You have something selected in the top bar where the icons are (house, bug etc) same happened to me once I turned the one that was selected off it worked again!

Answer (score 0):

You have to open a file from the Aptana file explorer under the main menu... File >> Open File...

Once you open a file the issue should be solved.